# r export summary info AND structure of data frame to csv file

Tags: r, csv, export, structure, export-to-csv

I have a dataframe in R (aa) that I imported to R from a SAS export file. It has over 350 variables. I want to export summary information about the variables to a csv file and have used this:

```
varsum = summary(aa)
write.csv(varsum, file = 'varsum.csv')
```

This gives me the variable name and min, max, NA's etc but I also want to include:

1. variable type (int, num etc)
2. variable label (an extended explanation of the variable that comes across with the XPT file. I can see this label when I used View under the variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your own function in `sapply` and include the information that you want.

```
varsum <- sapply(a, function(x) c(summary(x), type = class(x), label = ...))
write.csv(varsum, file = 'varsum.csv')
```

You can test this with `mtcars` dataset :

```
sapply(mtcars, function(x) c(summary(x), type = class(x)))
```

Comment: Thanks, Ronak
I could not get that to work with label. But I did it in the end in two steps and some excel jiggery-pokery... did not get a summary of variable type but in my case, they are all numerical.

I just needed a table to print out so I could quickly scan the variables and labels for the ones I want to use....diverted me for several hours !!!

varsum = summary(aa)
write.csv(varsum, file = 'varsum.csv')

varlab = get_label(aa, def.value = NULL, case = NULL)
write.csv(varlab, file = 'varlab.csv')

Comment: I mean you don't actually have to write `...` for `label`. It was not clear to me from your post how to get the label information for the data. Also there was no sample dataset shared to make a guess. Therefore, I left it blank for you to write it.

Comment: Thanks again Ronak. Yes that works. I misspelled label...Thanks